# How to call a function inside a form from a user control (C# Winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

So I have user control I want to hide/send to back and I want to call the public function in my form where the user control is, from the control itself.

I have a button in the user control with the following code:

```
mainboard MAIN = new mainboard(); // mainboard is a form to call to.
MAIN.PastLockScreen(); // PastLockScreen is a public void inside mainboard
```

When I click the button the public function in `mainboard` does not get called. There are no errors, what am I doing wrong, and how can I call a function in a form from a user control?

void inside `mainboard`

```
public void PastLockScreen()
{
   lockscreen1.SendToBack(); // lockscreen1 is the usercontrol that this function gets called from
}
```

The void is being referenced but not called?

> Edit: I have done some investigating and turns out that my timers I have in any form or control, also dont work. But buttons on the actual form itself do work. (and yes I did do `timerName.Start();` when the form/control loads.)

Solved the issue above, my timers needed to display time, which the time string I defined inside the class instead of inside the timer.tick

Comment: Is `MAIN` the *actual* reference to the user control you want to change? If not, you need a reference to the actual control rather than creating a totally new `mainboard`.

Comment: Have you [stepped through your code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019) to see if the method gets called and see what happens.

Comment: ```mainboard``` is a form, I want to call a function that is inside the from, from a user control.

Comment: You need to register the button with "+=".  Open the designer.cs file where button works to see example of how to register.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From within the UserControl, just cast [ParentForm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.parentform?view=net-5.0) to type `mainboard`:

```
// .. form within the UserControl that is CONTAINED by form mainboard ...
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mainboard MAIN = this.ParentForm as mainboard;
    if (MAIN != null)
    {
        MAIN.PastLockScreen();
    }
}
```

Note that this is a TIGHTLY COUPLED approach that limits your use of the UserControl to only mainboard.

A better approach would be to make the UserControl raise some kind of custom EVENT that the mainboard form then subscribes to.  When the event is received then the form itself would run the appropriate method.  This would mean you could potentially utilize the UserControl in a different form without changing any code within it.  This latter approach would be LOOSELY COUPLED.

Comment: I will try the solution, and ```mainboard``` is supposed to be the only form that has user controls, thank you for the answer. This will solve my issue but I will also look in to the better approach and maybe leave a comment here.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

**In Form1**

to Show the Form2

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
frm2.Show();
```

To call the method do you want

```
Form2 cmd = new Form2();
cmd.PastLockScreen();
```

**In Form2**

```
   public void PastLockScreen()
    {
        this.SendToBack();
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly what don't have to do.

Comment: This is to call a function in a form from another form, what I am talking about in my post is, how to call a function that is inside a form through a user control